# Json file not getting updated when using post method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, api

This is the js code for post:

```
async function invoice() {
    const baseurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getInvoice/';
    let response = await fetch(baseurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userId: 1,
            Total: 3333
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
}
```

This is the backend code:

```
public function getInvoice(Request $request){
    $invoice = json_encode($request->all());
    $result = file_put_contents(base_path('storage/app/invoice.json'),$invoice);
}
```

Each time while posting, it shows only one entry. i.e The content is overridden by another instead of creating new entries?

```
{
    userId: 1,
    Total: 3333
}
```

Comment: Your `getInvoice()` method would need to read the file and add the data to the existing data.  At the moment you just encode the request and overwrite the file.

Comment: Also if it comes as JSON, don't you double encode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for appending to a file instead of just overwriting it:

I've set the append flag and added a lock to the operation. Read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
public function getInvoice(Request $request){
    $invoice = json_encode($request->all());
    $result = file_put_contents(base_path('storage/app/invoice.json'), $invoice, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```